# How can I wait for data to be pushed into an array before loading charts?

Tags: angular

I'm trying to display some charts on my app, but they aren't displaying currently because I'm pushing the data that they need into an array after they are loading, thus empty charts. Is there any way to wait to wait on the array before trying to render my charts?

I've tried messing around with async and await, but I don't know if I'm doing it wrong or if it's just not going to help me in this case. I've tried putting a then on the end of my this.games.getAllGames() function and then calling the loadCharts() function in that but that doesn't work either.

```
export class SportsCardsComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
  currentPage = 1;
  chart: [];
  gamesArray = [];
  test = [];

  constructor(
    public games: GameService
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getGames();
  }

  async getGames() {
    const game = await this.games.getAllGames(this.currentPage);
    _.each(game.games, (gameData) => {
      this.gamesArray.push(gameData);
    });
  }

loadCharts() {
    _.each(this.gamesArray, (game) => {
      console.log('hello');
      this.chart = new Chart(game.id, {
        type: 'doughnut',
      data: {
        labels: [game.homeTeam.teamName, game.awayTeam.teamName],
        datasets: [
          {
            label: game.homeTeam.teamName + ' Vs ' + game.awayTeam.teamName,
            backgroundColor: [game.homeTeam.schoolPrimaryColor, game.awayTeam.schoolSecondaryColor],
            data: [game.homeTeam.totalBets, game.awayTeam.totalBets]
          }
        ]
      },
      options: {
        title: {
          display: true,
          text: game.homeTeam.teamName + ' Vs ' + game.awayTeam.teamName
        }
      }
      });
    });
  }
```

I'm wanting my charts to load, but the array the each is looking for doesn't have any data in it, so therefore the charts will not load.

HTML:

```
<div class="col-lg-9 float-right" >
  <!-- <div *ngIf='loading'  class="d-flex justify-content-center">
    <div class="spinner-border" style="width: 3rem; height: 3rem;" role="status"></div>
  </div> -->
  <!-- <div *ngIf="!loading"> -->
      <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-6 card-background"
            *ngFor="let game of gamesArray"
          >
            <div class="card-surround shadow-sm">
              <div>
                  <h2>{{game.homeTeam.teamName}}</h2>
                  <h2>{{game.awayTeam.teamName}}</h2>
                  <canvas id="{{game.id}}"></canvas>
                  <hr>
                  <p>{{game.gameTime}}</p>
              </div>
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
  <!-- </div> -->
  <ngb-pagination
  class="d-flex justify-content-end"
  [collectionSize]="gamesArray.length"
  [(page)]="currentPage"
  [maxSize]="5"
  [pageSize]='6'
  (pageChange)='onPageChange($event)'
  size="sm"
  [rotate]="true"
  [ellipses]="false"
  [boundaryLinks]="true"
  ></ngb-pagination>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `*ngIf` in your template:

```
<canvas id="{{game.id}}" *ngIf="gamesArray.length"></canvas>
```

This loads your chart only if the data is in your array.

Your chart does not load because your canvas does not have a reference with your component. And you are using a loop so I suggest you use **chartjs** wrapper for Angular. https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-chartjs

Comment: That just causes nothing to load at all.

Comment: I added the HTML to the original post

Comment: So everything loads but the chart

Comment: @Chameleon Your chart does not load because your `canvas` does not have a reference with your component. And you are using a loop so I suggest you use chartjs wrapper for Angular. https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-chartjs

Answer (score 0):

You can use the @ViewChild to trigger your chart

For example if you have in the Template something like that

```
    <div class="col-lg-6 card-background"  *ngFor="let game of gamesArray;let i=index" >

        <canvas baseChart  [id]="i" [datasets]="ChartData" [labels]="ChartLabels" [options]="ChartOptions" [legend]="ChartLegend" [chartType]="ChartType" </canvas>

</div>
```

In the ViewModel you can use

```
  @ViewChild('#1') firstChartttt: BaseChart;
```

You have now the object you can assign data here after checks and no need Of redraw while angular is Two-way bindings

NB: But don't forget to initiate the chart data

Comment: How would this look in my component file? I'm not really familiar with @ViewChild or how to trigger them, do you happen to have a good resource for me to read?

Comment: @ViewChild is so powerful, you can trigger everything you want in your template 

Please take a look at this https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-viewchild/

Comment: Try always to do business logic into your ViewModel and avoid charging your Template with  *ngIf because it is impacting the first rendering of your application

Comment: `@ViewChild('yourChart') yourChartttt: BaseChart;` This might not work for him since he is looping and creating multiple dynamic charts.

Comment: Yes, it will be so difficult for him to trigger it if it' is generating many canvas without '#id' using *NgFor so he need to care about data duplication, so the trigger will never be done from the ModelView

Comment: @YoussefTounoussi I have multiple charts on the same page yes, right now they are being created dynamically as you state.

Comment: So for solve this you just need to generate dynamic ID for each canvas created by using in your *NgFor an index that you will pass it as in my edited answer now above